# Gridview.Rows WPF

Tags: wpf, gridview, row

I have a Gridview in my WPF app and in my code I wanna use the .Rows property but I can't find it
MyGridview.Rows dosn't exist

How can i fix this?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GridView` is just a view, it is  not meant for item management, you can access the items (which are the rows) from the owner `ListView.Items`.

Comment: is it posible to color a row depending on the value of a cell?

Comment: @ParysBernard: Yes it is, put a comment is not the place to ask for this, it's completely unrelated, also i am **very sure** that this has been asked and answered before.